# Get camera field of view in iOS 11 ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm using a ARSCNView from ARKit to display live a video feed from the camera on the iPad. I have the ARSCNView object setup exactly as Xcode's Augmented Reality App template. I was wondering if there is a way to get the field of view of the camera?

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

func start() {
    sceneView.delegate = self
    sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    // Retrieve camera FOV here
}
```

Comment: How about `sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.xFov`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go here, and a possible false start to beware of.

#### ⚠️ ARKit + SceneKit (incorrect)

If you're already working with ARKit via SceneKit (`ARSCNView`), you might assume that ARKit is automatically updating the SceneKit camera (the view's [`pointOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview)'s [`camera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407976-camera)) to match the projection transform used by ARKit. This is correct.

However, ARKit directly sets the `SCNCamera`'s [`projectionTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1690501-projectiontransform). When you work with geometric properties of `SCNCamera` like `zNear` and `zFar` and [`fieldOfView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/2867510-fieldofview), SceneKit derives a projection matrix for use in rendering. But if you set [`projectionTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1690501-projectiontransform) directly, there's no math that can recover the near/far and xFov/yFov values, so the corresponding `SCNCamera` properties are invalid. That is, **`sceneView.pointOfView.camera.fieldOfView` and similar APIs always return bogus results for an ARKit app**.

So, what can you do instead? Read on...

#### Projection Matrix

An AR session continually vends [`ARFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe) objects through its delegate, or you can request the [`currentFrame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2865621-currentframe) from it. Each frame has an [`ARCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera) attached that describes the imaging parameters, one of which is a [`projectionMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix) that's dependent on field of view. (There's also the aforementioned SceneKit `projectionTransform`, which is the same matrix.)

A standard 3D projection matrix includes scaling terms that are based on the vertical field of view and aspect ratio. Specifically, the matrix looks like this:

```
[ xScale    0     0    0  ]   xScale = yScale * aspectRatio (width/height)
[   0    yScale   0    0  ]   yScale = 1 / tan(yFov/2)
[   0       0    nf1  nf2 ]   nf1 and nf2 relate to near and far clip planes,
[   0       0     -1   0  ]     so aren't relevant to field of view
```

So you should be able to get `yFov` by solving the `yScale` equation:

```
let projection = session.currentFrame!.camera.projectionMatrix
let yScale = projection[1,1]
let yFov = 2 * atan(1/yScale) // in radians
let yFovDegrees = yFov * 180/Float.pi
```

And for horizontal field of view, you can multiply by the aspect ratio (specifically, the width/height ratio):

```
let imageResolution = session.currentFrame!.camera.imageResolution
let xFov = yFov * Float(imageResolution.width / imageResolution.height)
```

> **Note:** Here, "horizontal" and "vertical" are with respect to the camera image, which is natively in landscape orientation regardless of how your device or AR view UI are oriented.

If you look closely, though, you might notice that the aspect ratio between `xFov`/`yFov` here (and the aspect ratio of `imageResolution`) don't necessarily match that of your device screen (especially on iPhone X) or the view you're drawing AR content in. That's because you've measured the FOV angles *of the camera image*, not those of your app's AR view. Don't worry, there's an API for that, too...

#### Projection Matrix with Viewport

`ARCamera` offers two APIs for getting a projection matrix. Besides the one we just went over, there's also [`projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrix), which takes presentation into account. If you want to match not the FOV of the camera, but the FOV of how `ARSCNView` or `ARSKView` (or Unity or Unreal, probably?) render your AR scene, use this, passing the device orientation and see of your view. Then do all the same math as above:

```
let imageResolution = session.currentFrame!.camera.imageResolution
let viewSize = sceneView.bounds.size
let projection = session.currentFrame!.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .portrait,
    viewportSize: viewSize, zNear: zNear, zFar: zFar)
let yScale = projection[1,1] // = 1/tan(fovy/2)
let yFovDegrees = 2 * atan(1/yScale) * 180/Float.pi
let xFovDegrees = yFovDegrees * Float(viewSize.height / viewSize.width)
```

What you pass for `zNear` and `zFar` doesn't matter, since we're not using the parts of the matrix that depend on that. (You might still need to ensure `zNear < zFar` and `zNear != zFar != 0`.)

> **Note:** Now the height/width are based on your view (or rather, the attributes of your view that you pass to `projectionMatrix(for:...)`). In this example, `yFov` is vertical with respect to the UI because the orientation is `portrait`, so you multiply by the height/width aspect ratio to get `xFov`. If you're in landscape, you multiply by width/height instead.

#### Camera Intrinsics

Keen observers may have noticed that the above calculations ignore parts of the projection matrix. That's because the [definition of FOV angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view) is an optical property of the camera, not anything to do with 3D projection, so a whole projection matrix is an intermediate result you might not really need.

`ARCamera` also exposes an [`intrinsics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2875730-intrinsics) matrix that describes optical properties of the camera. The first and second values along the diagonal in this matrix are the horizontal and vertical [focal length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length) of a single pixel in the camera image. If you have focal length and image width/height, you can compute FOV per the [definition of FOV angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view#Derivation_of_the_angle-of-view_formula):

```
let imageResolution = session.currentFrame!.camera.imageResolution
let intrinsics = session.currentFrame!.camera.intrinsics
let xFovDegrees = 2 * atan(Float(imageResolution.width)/(2 * intrinsics[0,0])) * 180/Float.pi
let yFovDegrees = 2 * atan(Float(imageResolution.height)/(2 * intrinsics[1,1])) * 180/Float.pi
```

> **Note:** Like the version that uses `projectionMatrix`, this is based on the size and always-landscape orientation of the *camera image*, not the device screen or the view you're displaying AR content in. If you need something based on the viewport instead, scroll back up to "Projection Matrix with Viewport".

Comment: This is the best answer on Earth.

Comment: Really helpful. 2 questions - 1. Is there a way for me to find out the horizontal FOV? ie if the user were to point the camera straight forwards, what would the FOV be there? 2. I tested this by adding 360 nodes to my scene, around the user. Result was that I could see 31 of them, yet xFOVDegrees returned either 45 or 60, depending on which of the bottom 2 methods I used. So that'd suggest the xFOV is actually 31?

Comment: Wow this helped me understand why I'm getting errors in some other task. I have a AR engine written using SceneKit and camera preview (simpler version of ark), and I have a problem with scale of objects in it. I used to set the fieldOfView in SceneKit to exact fieldOfView of camera format (about 58), and objects were looking just a bit too large. Now by printing ARKit values like you described I see that when camera is focusing on different distance, this fieldOfView is changing as well. This would explain why scale of my objects was a little off.

Comment: Would you happened to know how can I adjust this FieldOfView that I read from cameraFormat to current focus of camera, so that it would look correct? I read a value of over 58 degrees, and I think I should multiply this by some value from camera session or apply some other correction, but I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: I'm guessing all these values are for video modes, not for still images, right?

Comment: Hello @DamianDudycz, would you happen to know if we can just use projection matrix to get 3d point to 2d points with ARKit/scenekit?

Comment: This truly is the best answer on Earth. It applies to RealityKit as well as SceneKit.

Answer (score -5):

Or you could just do:

```
sceneView.pointOfView?.camera?.fieldOfView
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this work?