# How can I calculate the projection matrix given by ARKit's ARCamera?

Tags: matrix, 3d, arkit, projection, metal

I'm trying to reverse-engineer ARCamera's [projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrix), but I'm getting wrong values for `m[2][0]` and `m[2][1]` (column-major). Here's what I got so far (I'm using landscapeRight orientation):

```
// intrinsics:
//   933.9137        0.0   617.7059
//        0.0   933.9137   363.0624
//        0.0        0.0        1.0
//
// viewportSize:
//   width: 700.0, height: 300.0
//
// imageSize (obtained from ARKit's camera):
//   width: 1280.0, height: 720.0
//
// zNear: 0.007, zFar: 1300.0
//
// Calculated matrix:
//   1.4592402         0.0   0.034834575            0.0
//         0.0   3.4048939   0.034834575            0.0
//         0.0         0.0    -1.0000054   -0.007000038
//         0.0         0.0          -1.0            0.0
//
// Expected matrix from projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:):
//   1.4592401         0.0   0.034053326           0.0
//         0.0   3.4048936   0.012987971           0.0
//         0.0         0.0    -1.0000054  -0.007000038
//         0.0         0.0          -1.0           0.0

func calculateProjectionMatrix(intrinsics: simd_float3x3,
                               viewportSize: Size,
                               imageSize: Size,
                               zNear: Float,
                               zFar: Float) -> simd_float4x4 {

    let aspect = viewportSize.height / viewportSize.width
    let right: Float = imageSize.width - intrinsics[2][0]
    let left: Float = -intrinsics[2][0]
    let top: Float = right * aspect
    let bottom: Float = left * aspect

    return simd_float4x4(
        simd_float4(2 * intrinsics[0][0] / (right - left), 0, 0, 0),
        simd_float4(0, 2 * intrinsics[1][1] / (top - bottom), 0, 0),
        simd_float4((right + left) / (right - left), (top + bottom) / (top - bottom), -zFar / (zFar - zNear), -1.0),
        simd_float4(0, 0, -zFar * zNear / (zFar - zNear), 0)
    )
}
```

It seems that I'm not setting `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` correctly. I know I ignored `intrinsics[2][1]`, which I probably shouldn't, but even the result that depended only on `right` and `left` (`m[2][0]`) is wrong.

I read some blog posts (e.g., [1](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/), [2](https://metashapes.com/blog/opengl-metal-projection-matrix-problem/))  about this (most of them about OpenGL) but I couldn't get the exact matrix given by this method. Do you have any thoughts of what's wrong with my implementation and what should I do to get the same results as ARKit's function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536580/get-camera-field-of-view-in-ios-11-arkit

Comment: I wouldn’t say it’s a duplicate exactly but the answer you linked brings a lot of useful information to answer my question. Thank you a lot. I’m going to check it carefully later today (because right now I’m on my cellphone).

Comment: I trying to solve this same problem. Did you ever find a solution?